# Update table with different conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables and want to update one of them based on the values in the other one. When an id matches then I want to update the column availability = 'offsite' else 'onsite'.
I tried the following but it is taking too much time. Can anyone provide me an optimal solution for this?

```
update target T                             
set 
availability = case 
when T1.availability is not null then  'offsite'
else 'onsite' end        
FROM
(select FT.id, FT.availability from target FT 
left join
source IT
on 
FT.id = IT.id ) T1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
UPDATE T 

SET T.availability = CASE WHEN T.availability IS NOT NULL THEN  'offsite' ELSE 'onsite' END

FROM target T 
LEFT JOIN source IT
ON FT.id = IT.id
```